# Is it true that $D(\mathcal{O}_Y\text-\mathrm{mod}_X)\cong D_X(\mathcal{O}_Y\text-\mathrm{mod})$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homological-algebra

Is it true that $D(Y_X)\cong D_X(Y)$, where $Y$ is a (smooth) variety, $X$ is a closed subvariety of $Y$ (possibly singular)? Here $D(Y_X)$ denotes the derived category of the abelian category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $Y$ that are supported on $X$ (that is $I_XF=0$, where $I_X$ is the ideal defining $X$), and $D_X(Y)$ is the full subcategory of $D(Y)$ consists of complexes with cohomology supported on $X$. Furthermore, can we see something on the bounded level?

Comment: Is the question in your title ("Is it true that $D(\mathcal O_Y\text-\mathrm{mod}_X) \cong D_X(\mathcal O_Y\text-\mathrm{mod}$?") the same as the question in your body ("Is it true that $D(Y_X) \cong D_X(Y) …?")?

Comment: It is a consequence of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0955